# Issues in setting the PNG image in relative layout in android

Tags: android

I have displayed an PNG image in relative layout using XML code in android at the bottom of screen but it there is small gap between the image bottom and the base and i want that image should touch the base.

Comment: set relative layout gravity bottom and try it

Answer (score 0):

Try **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**.

It may be solve your query.

Thanks.